# QGIS2WEB with omnivore

Tags: leaflet, javascript, qgis-plugins, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've used QGIS2WEB to output a leaflet map, all of which works well. It's a simple map showing markers, I want the markers to update based on a csv which is updated daily. Omnivore looks like my solution, so i've tried to edit the code QGIS2WEB gives me.

I can see that the CSV in QGIS is converted to a geojson file (i think) and stored in the data folder as;

`csv_data.js`

This is then called in the main html file using

`<script src="data/csv_data.js"></script>`.

I've tried editing the contents of the `csv_data.js` from;

```
var csv_data = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": 
"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
```

to

```
var csv_data = omnivore.csv(url)
```

I'm using the mapbox omnivore library with a call to that in the main body of the html using;

`<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.3.1/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>`

But this returns no markers, the folder structure is as QGIS2WEB output as screen grab.

[image]

In the console i get two errors;

`Uncaught ReferenceError: omnivore is not defined` &
`Uncaught ReferenceError: csv_data is not defined`

I'm new to javascript and html so not sure whhat is causing either of these

Comment: Are you loading omnivore before using it? The execution order matters.

Comment: I think so, i assume putting it at the start of the main html means it should call first? Or should i put it in the csv_data.js file before the `var csv_data = omnivore.csv(url) ` ?